# Building a dictionary tuple from a TXT file, Output another TXT file to test the accuracy of my dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, printing

Using python 3.6 in Spyder

I am trying to create a code where I get the following:

> -make a dictionary tuple that will keep track of the count showing how often the word and tag appear together in the list
>
> -output the file with a print statement that will give a txt file with the same style as the input file (word position, word, tag)

I'm doing this so I can use it with another input file without the last column (word position, word) and will assign tags based on what I have in my dictionary.

Input file is as shown (fields are TAB separated):

> 1   i   PRP
>
> 2   want    VBP
>
> 3   to  TO
>
> 4   go  VB

The code I have so far is this

```
file=open("/Users/Desktop/training.txt").read().split('\n')

d = {}
for i in file:
    if i[1:] in d.keys():
        d[i[1:]] += 1
    else:
        d[i[1:]] = 1

with open('/Users/Desktop/2output.txt', 'w') as file:
for nested_list in d.keys():
    for word in nested_list:
         file.write(word + '\t')
         file.write('\n')
```

with the entire code i'm getting results like this:
i

i

P
R
P

'
d

M
D

l
i
k
e

V
B

So I am throwing away the word position in my code. My questions are:

How can I keep the word position in my code?

why am i getting one character per line?

Thank you very much. All help is much appreciated.

Comment: I'd like to write some code for you, but I'm not clear on what the output corresponding to that input should look like. That `('\tstuffed\tVBD', 8), ('\tinn\tIN', 8), ('\ttaiwan\tNN', 8), ('6\tno\tDT', 8)` is a bit confusing because it doesn't correspond to the input you posted.

Comment: That `i[1:]` isn't a good idea. It will only work if the word position is a single digit number. And as you noticed, it doesn't deal with the tabs correctly.

Comment: Also, your code throws away the word position info, so I don't see how you expect to get (word position, word, tag) in the output.

Comment: in your first comment, ('\tstuffed\tVBD', 8) refers to the results I'm getting with a standard print statement, not in the txt output i'm trying to get. the d[i[1:] was for the count, i changed this to `counts = defaultdict(Counter)
for row in file:         
    if not row.strip():
        continue          
    pos, word, tag = row.split()
    counts[word.lower()][tag] += 1
    ` for count and word position but i'm still getting single characters per line, do you have any suggestions??

Comment: Sorry, I can't suggest anything if you can't explain or show us what your actual desired output is. BTW, there's no point posting multi-line Python code in comments because the indentation gets lost, making the code virtually unreadable. But anyway, `defaultdict(Counter)` doesn't make much sense here. It creates a separate Counter for each word that counts the different tags for that word. I don't understand why you'd want to do that.

Comment: but i am trying to keep track of the word and the different tags that appear for the word. this is a baseline code to create a dictionary so i can take new word sets without a a tag column and get their tags for words that overlap in my dictionary. this issue I'm on now is the printing. Thanks though your comments have helped!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Everything basically worked except for the writing statement which is outputting a file I can't find anywhere, no bug but its just not working

Your problem may be that you don't provide a full path when you open the write file. Earlier in the program you read `"/Users/Desktop/training.txt"` but later you open `'2output.txt'`, without the full path included. I would try opening `'/Users/Desktop/2output.txt'` and see if the output file is saved in your Desktop folder.

Comment: thank you!!! that worked, but now the file is coming out with each character per line, i'll edit my post to show what the new results look like, thank you for your help again

Comment: I don't think you'll get an answer unless you post your *desired* output alongside your *actual* output. If you edit your question to show what you want the program to produce given your example input, I can probably figure out what's wrong.